# Como somar dois floats interagindo com a UI?

Tags: android, float

Eu queria somar dois floats, mas eu coloco o primeiro número decimal no `EditText` e quando vou adicionar mais um número decimal, eu coloco no `EditText` marco no `CheckBox` e ele continua o mesmo número que eu coloquei no `CheckBox`.

Exemplo: Coloquei 1.5

Aí quando eu apago o 1.5 do meu `EdiText` e coloco mais 1.5 e marco um dos `CheckBox`,
Fica na realidade 1.5 em vez de ficar 3.0 no resultado do `TextView`.

```
package com.gustavo.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CheckBox g;
    CheckBox m;
    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bacon();

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String counter = num.getText().toString();

                float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);

                float geof = 0f;
                float matf = 0f;


                  if(g.isChecked()){
                      float res1 = geof += counterAsFloat;
                      say.setText("Geo " + Float.toString(res1));
                  }
                  else if(m.isChecked()){
                      float res2 = matf += counterAsFloat;
                    say.setText("Math " + Float.toString(res2));
                  }

            }
        });
    }
    public void bacon() {
        g = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        m = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
    }

}
```

Comment: Blz vlw já consertei os erros ...

Comment: @bigown você sabe qual o problema do meu codigo então é pq estou tentando somar dessa maneira mais não sei se existe outras ?

Comment: Foi mal ai @bigown cliquei sem querer no botão reverter...

Comment: Estou tentando entender essa lógica, parece algo muito esquisito. Não conheço a UI do Android e o sistema de eventos dele mas pra mim é estranho você inicializar `geof` e `matf` e depois tentar acumular nele. Me parece óbvio que sempre vai zerar e antes de fazer qualquer soma, então sempre vai dar o resultado inicial e não a soma. Mas pode ser que tenha algo específico da tecnologia que eu não sei que seja diferente. Está me parecendo que este `geof`e `mat` deveriam ser campos da classe e não variáveis locais, só um chute.

Comment: Se eu fizesse isso daria para armazenar o valor que eu coloquei no `EditText` e depois somar com outro valor que eu coloquei no `EditText` ? @bigown

Comment: Na realidade não sei se da para somar por isso que perguntei aqui.

Comment: @bigown Você está correto, as variáveis `geof` e `matf` deveriam ter sido declaradas como de instância e não locais. E `res1` e `res2` são desnecessárias.

Comment: Não se entendi seu objetivo e como está todo o código mas acho que solucionaria o problema. Você tentou agora e conseguiu o que queria? E sim, essas variáveis são desnecessárias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alterar seu código para:

Layout activity_main:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Digite numero:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Geo" />

         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Math" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="somar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Código MainActivity:

```
package com.gustavo.sample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;
    CheckBox g;
    CheckBox m;
    float geof = 0;
    float matf = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        g = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        m = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String counter = num.getText().toString();
                if (counter.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Digite um valor numerico", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);
                    if (g.isChecked() && m.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione apenas um checkbox",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (m.isChecked()) {
                        matf = matf + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Math " + Float.toString(matf));
                    } else if (g.isChecked()) {
                        geof = geof + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Geo " + Float.toString(geof));
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione um checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Na realidade eu não quero apenas somar dois números eu quero somar quantos números eu quizer mais sempre que eu adicionar um número no `EditText` ele vai somar com outra coisa e mostrar na `TextView`.

Comment: @GustavoDibai na realidade olha sua pergunta... Como somar dois floats interagindo com a UI? creio que seu pergunta está respondida

Comment: @GustavoDibai você tinha marcado como respondida anteriormente mas se vc deseja somar mais numeros e só fazer o que foi dito abaixo como exemplo após o código: por exemplo somar 3+4+5 ... coloque 3 marque checkbox depois desmarque coloque 4 depois você pode colocar 5 e marcar novamente o checkbox e apertar send

Comment: Beleza vou testar o código se der certo eu marco a resposta como certa ;)

Comment: E sobre a minha pergunta ela está certa porque os dois floats que eu estou querendo somar é `geof` e `matf` ...

Comment: @GustavoDibai vc nao precisa de 2 variaveis pra somar....

Comment: Sim eu sei mais essas duas variaveis vão somar ao valor que eu colocar no `EditText` e marcar no `CheckBox` e clicar no `Button`

Comment: Mais na realidade seu codigo não me da essa opção de escolher os `CheckBox` porque quando eu clico no botão no seu codigo você já esta me redirecionando para o primeiro `CheckBox`.

Comment: @GustavoDibai editei nao precisa desses checkbox sao inuteis... mostrei o layout q criei.. nao ta muito bonito mas so pra teste mesmo... entao e so vc colocar o numero e depois clicar em somar e assim por diante...

Comment: mais mano você não ta entendendo meu aplicativo precisa desses `CheckBox` para você selecionar qual opção você quer colocar o valor.

Comment: e logo depois o valor fica amarzenado dentro da quela checkbox...

Comment: consertei copia o codigo pra ver se atende oq vc quer... o layout e mainactivity

Comment: Nossa vlw mano precisava mto disso...

Comment: @GustavoDibai foi um prazer ajudar vou dar +1 no seu post.